# How many random picks to have a $> 50$% chance of picking an item from a weighted list?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

##### Base Problem

Say I have a list of weighted choices, like:

```
As Defined    or    Normalized
----------          ----------
A:   10.00          A:   0.274
B:    8.00          B:   0.219
C:    6.67          C:   0.183
D:    5.00          D:   0.137
E:    3.33          E:   0.091
F:    2.50          F:   0.068
G:    1.00          G:   0.027
```

Let $w_x$ be the weight for some item $x$.
Let $n$ be some number of random picks (with replacement).
Let $p$ be the probability that $x$ will appear at least once within $n$ picks.

How can I compute the answer to the following question?

> For a given $w_x$, what is the smallest $n$ such that $p$ ≥ 0.5?

Informally: how many picks will it take until I'm likely to see $x$?

---

##### Bonus Problem

I'd love to know the inverse as well. That is:

> For a given $x$ and $n_{desired}$: if all other weights are held constant, what should be $w_x$ so that $n$ ≥ $n_{desired}$?

This is what I'm really trying to figure out. I want to be able to pick an $n_{desired}$ for each $x$ and have the weights computed.

It seems like a much harder question, but maybe not? I figured if I could get an answer to the base problem, I could muck about in a spreadsheet changing weights until I get my $n_{desired}$'s ☺

---

**Thanks!**

Comment: If the picks are independent, then the probability that $x$ is never chosen in $n$ picks is exactly $(1-w_x)^n$ (I assume $w_x$ denotes the normalized weight). Both of your questions can be answered by setting this expression equal to $\frac12$ and then solving for whichever variable you're not assigning a value to.

Comment: I suspect that you can change $w_k$ only. If you change one weight, then at least another weight must be changed

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @joriki thanks. Just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With replacement, the problem is trivial as first noted by Greg Martin:
$$\Pr(x\text{ is chosen in }n\text{ picks})=1-(1-w_x)^n$$
which is a standard formula, found by considering the probability you *don't* pick $x$, $n$ times in a row.

It is equally trivial to solve it for $p=0.5$:
$$\begin{align}1-(1-w_x)^n&\geq0.5\\\Rightarrow n&\geq\frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(1-w_x)}\end{align}$$
which is also standard.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely answers the base problem. How would I factor this to solve for $w_x$? Is it $w_x = 1 - 0.5^{1/n}$?

Comment: After some testing, that does seem to be correct, except I forgot it was an inequality. So $w_x \ge 1 - 0.5^{1/n}$. Then to get the final weight: $w_x = \left(1 - 0.5^{1/n}\right) * \left( \frac{1}{\sum w_x} \right)$

Comment: @JuanP yep you did that correctly